# Firestore query is not being executed

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing a weird issue, and i have tried to debug, enter logs etc but still reached no where with this. I am trying to retrive data from firestore. This data is easily recovered using the same code in other activities. But in this one, its like the code doesnt exist. It doesnt enter any of the .addOnSuccess or .addOnFailure loops. Just moves over them - any thoughts?

```
 try {
    //Retrieving availability data from Firestore for the service Provider
    val mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("Users")
        .document(serviceProvider!!.getUID()!!)
        .collection("bookingOptions")
        .document(serviceProvider!!.getUID()!!)

        Log.e("BookingOption try started", serviceProvider!!.getUID()!!)
        mFirestore.get().addOnCompleteListener {
            Log.e("BookingOption query executed", serviceProvider!!.getUID()!!)
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                val document = it.result
                bookingConditions = document.toObject(Bakala::class.java)
                Log.i("BookingOption retrieved", it.toString())
                //Device timezone if it is the client then the client device timezone
                selectedCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault())
                //saving the the provider timezone id
                providerTimeZoneID = bookingConditions!!.gettimeZoneId().toString()
                Log.e("TimeZone Data obtained", providerTimeZoneID)
                //get current time in company timezone id
                //convert to user timezone
                val minDate =
                    Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(bookingConditions!!.gettimeZoneId()))
                FORMAT.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
                val date = FORMAT.format(minDate.time)
                try {
                    minDate.time = FORMAT.parse(date)
                } catch (e: ParseException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener {
     

       Log.e("BookingOption retrieval failure", it.toString())
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry could not load company info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//            finish()
            }.addOnCanceledListener {
                Log.e("BookingOption retrieval failure", "Query cancelled")
            }
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e("BookingOptions failure",e.message.toString())
        }
```

Comment: `Log.e("BookingOption query executed", serviceProvider!!.getUID()!!)` does this log show up?

Comment: Are you sure you have internet connection on user device?

Comment: yes, internet is working, and the serviceProvider Id displays. No listeners for the query execute

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, asynchronous execution of later functions that uses data from the above code ran quicker and caused a crash. Included that function in the successlistener for the query and it worked...